# Loop through range to show/hide rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Old VBA dog trying to learn new JS tricks.

I need to modify the code below to return the row number when the cell value ="Show"

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //active workbook
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //active sheet
    var range = sheet.getRange("ShowHideRows")
    range.getValues().forEach(function(row) {
        row.forEach(function(cell) {
            if (cell == "Show") {
                  sheet.showRows(cell)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Questions should include a brief description of the search/research efforts. Please, take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
function MyFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //active workbook
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //active sheet
    var range = sheet.getRange("ShowHideRows")

    range.getValues().forEach(function(row, rowIndex) {
        row.forEach(function(cell) {
            if (cell == "Show") {
                sheet.showRows(cell);
                return rowIndex;
            }
        });
   });
}
```

You can pass in the `.forEach` method both a value and an index.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, your suggestion worked. Here is a copy of the final code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ruben, your suggestion worked. The purpose of the code is facilitate filtering the display of table rows. In this case, there is a column with a range name 'ShowHideRows' left and adjacent to the table. The code will iterate through each row in the 'ShowHideRows' and hide the row if the cell = "Hide". Here's the working code.

```
function hideRows() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //active workbook
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //active sheet
    var range = sheet.getRange("ShowHideRows");
    var firstRow = range.getRow();

    range.getValues().forEach(function(row, rowIndex) {
        row.forEach(function(cell) {
            if (cell == "Hide") {
                sheet.hideRows(rowIndex + firstRow);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2V66.png)